# Show Table Name From Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a SELECT staement where I JOIN 2 separate tables.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM gslil0009) as table1 UNION SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM gslil0028) as table2' . ' ORDER BY lname');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['fname'];
}
```

How do I print out which table the row came from?

Answer (score 2):

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT *,'tbl1' FROM (SELECT * FROM gslil0009) as table1 
               UNION SELECT *,'tbl2' FROM (SELECT * FROM gslil0028) as table2' 
               . ' ORDER BY lname');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['fname'];
  echo $row['tbl1'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the same solution as sel just add backslash to avoid error and added a name to the table names.

```
$result = mysql_query('SELECT *,\'table1\' AS tablename FROM (SELECT * FROM gslil0009) as table1 
               UNION SELECT *,\'table2\' AS tablename FROM (SELECT * FROM gslil0028) as table2' 
               . ' ORDER BY lname');

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
  echo $row['fname'];
  echo $row['tablename'];
}
```

i couldn't add comment on his post.